# DVD/CD RW drive doesn't display or play in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, cd-drive

how do I get CDRW/DVDRW drive to show on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop? I have ubuntu host and windows 10 VM. I can get the drive to display and play in Windows; but, it doesn't show in ubuntu. Tried to burn audio disk using brasero but drive doesn't show. Doesn't play CDs either in Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I mucked up. Ubuntu is host and windows is vm

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354322/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-physical-cd-into-a-virtualbox-machine